# Nucleo-F767ZI won't start if powered through external 5V

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, nucleo, st

I'm trying to power a Nucleo-F767ZI demoboard through external 5V(through E5V pin).

When it's powered by USB, the code runs as expected(some LEDs blink), but when i attach the external 5V, and i switch power source with a jumper, the code doesn't run until i plug a usb cable or i perform a reset.

I tryed to remove the solder bridge SB111 (to remove the connection between the STM32 nRST and the STLink) and to add the solder bridge to SB1(to bypass the USB power regulator), but the problem persists.
Sometimes the code starts immediately, sometimes it is necessary to perform a reset.

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are doing, you may need to spend more time with the schematics, but keep in mind that you shouldn't have the target MCU powered with the ST-LINK MCU unpowered while there remain any connections between them, including SWD and UART

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the same issue, did you solve it somehow?